# Keeping first letter uppercase and rest lowercase with International letter support

Tags: php

I am using this code to keep first letter uppercase and rest lowercase but it doesn't support international latin letters. What should i add to make it support?

```
str_replace('\' ', '\'', ucwords(str_replace('\'', '\' ', strtolower($name))))
```

EDIT: ucfirst doesn't do it because i need each word's first letter uppercase

Example: HELLO BABY HOW ARE YOU

I need it like: Hello Baby How Are You

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-case.php ?

Comment: Not many people here read the subject line. ucfirst() won't work here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for international chars also:

```
mb_convert_case($str, MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ucwords](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php) with [strtolower](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php)

```
$string ="HELLO BABY HOW ARE YOU";
echo ucwords(strtolower($string));
```

Outputs :

```
Hello Baby How Are You.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first use `strtolower` to make the string lowercase before passing to `ucwords`.

`ucwords` does work with international characters, providing the correct locale is set.

See documentation on `setlocale`:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

You will need to set `LC_CTYPE` which is used for character classification and conversion.

Example for German characters:

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'de');
$a = ucwords(strtolower($b));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code:

```
function capitalizeFirstLetter($sentence){
    $result = "";
    $words = explode(" ", $sentence);
    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($words); $i++){
        $words[$i] = strtolower($words[$i]);
        $words[$i] = ucfirst($words[$i]);
        $result .= $words[$i];
        if($i != (sizeof($words) - 1)){
            $result .= " ";
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

$test = "HELLO BABY HOW ARE YOU";
echo capitalizeFirstLetter($test);
```

I couldn't find a way to avoid a loop.

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at using `ucfirst`? Here is the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php).

Someone posted code for a `sentence_case` version `ucfirst` in the comments section.